# read(fd, NULL, 0); what does it do? is it well-defined?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver

I've seen following statement in a few programs, most/all seem to be made for Linux.

```
rv = read(fd, NULL, 0);
```

In some programs it's in a loop, in some a single statement.

What does it do really?

Man page says that an invocation like this may or may not check for errors...

What is the significance of return value?

What types of file descriptors are supported?

And if `rv==0` how to distinguish "no error" from e.g. "socket closed".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This call will do all the usual error checking on the file descriptor, but not retrieve any data from it. This is useful if you wish to for example determine if the file descriptor is still valid without blocking on it.

It will return `-1` if an error occurs and `0` otherwise. Most of the errors listed in `man 2 read` can be queried in this way and will be returned in `errno`.

For example a return value of `-1` and `errno` of `EBADF` will be retuned if the file descriptor is closed. Instead return value will be `0` if everything is good and another `read` will not return an error that is associated with the validity of the file descriptor.

A subsequent `read` with a real buffer and `nbyte > 0` can still generate any number of errors like `ENOMEM`, `EAGAIN`, ...

Comment: It seems fundamentally non-portable.  The linux man (3) read page says: `Implementations are allowed, but not required, to perform error checking for read() requests of zero bytes.`POSIX says: Before any action is taken, and if nbyte is zero, the read() function *may* detect and return errors.