# How to tell, what "exceptional condition" caused select() to react to errorfds?

Tags: c, unix, select, low-level-io

According to its man page, the [select()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) system call offers monitoring of three different aspects of one or more file descriptors: whether they are ready to read from, ready to write to, or whether an "error" or "exceptional condition" (language varies) has occurred. Which of these shall be monitored, is specified via three `fd_set` arguments referred to as `readfds`, `writefds`, and `errorfds`. While there is plenty of good documentation and examples about the proper use of `readfds` and `writefds`, I could hardly find anything useful on `errorfds`.

Anyhow, for reasons discussed below, I gave the use of `errorfds` a try, and did indeed find a few circumstances, in which the `select()` call in my runloop responded to an "exceptional condition" on one of its file descriptors. For example, a TTY connected to a PTY, while the latter is being closed from its master side, raises such a condition.

But now what? I know that some "exceptional condition" occurred on a file descriptor, but how, in general, can I find out what exactly caused it? Just looking at `errno` certainly does not give the answer (at that point it is always 0). Is there perhaps some "magical" `ioctl` that I should be aware of?

**Some further background:** A number of my programs (mostly written in C) communicate with external hardware via serial ports. For testing, I also wrote a simple server that creates a PTY to which's corresponding TTY my other programs can connect to as if it was a serial port. While at a basic level all of this is working pretty well, handling of errors or other exceptional conditions is currently not really implemented at all, which occasionally leads to pretty nasty behavior. This needs to change!

One exceptional condition, that I am particularly interested in detecting, is whether a connection has been broken. For example, it would be nice to notice when a port goes away, say, because the user pulled a USB-to-serial adapter. Properly handling read and write errors seems to avoid the nastiest of unintended side effects, but I was wondering if there was more (watching `errorfds`, or perhaps some other signals) that I should be doing. Unfortunately, UNIX signal handling is something I am not at all familiar with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342712/nix-select-and-exceptfds-errorfds-semantics

Comment: I am aware of that other question just pointed out, which is indeed very similar to mine. However, did not feel that it matches exactly. In fact, from the answers given there, I wonder if there is any answer to my question, other than "not possible to use `errorfds` for this use case" ... But would like to know for sure before moving on.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that some "exceptional condition" occurred on a file descriptor, but how, in general, can I find out what exactly caused it? Is there perhaps some "magical" ioctl that I should be aware of?

You should try reading 0 bytes. In linux, at least, `man 2 read` states:

> If count is zero, read() may detect the errors described below.

So, after `read(fd, NULL,0)` you should have an `errno` that tells you something more, without having to actually read anything. The weasel word *may* in the manpage means that this is probably not very portable, though (cf [read(fd, NULL, 0); what does it do? is it well-defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112402/readfd-null-0-what-does-it-do-is-it-well-define))

Comment: To be safer, you might supply a valid pointer to some allocated memory and request 0 bytes: `char c; if (read(fd, &c, 0) < 0) { …errno has some information in it… }`.  However, you might still get an EINVAL error for passing 0 bytes to the function (system call).

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, that should be more reliable, but,  as it is non-portable, YMMV anyway. In the scenario Steven is interested in (broken connection), the `select()` will be interrupted by a `SIGHUP` anyway, even without setting the `errorfds`. I suspect that catching `SIGHUP` will be a more portable and reliable way to sense a broken connection than the `read(fd,NULL,0)` trick